# operator in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the effective way of this code?I think there should be better way.I wanna re-code this.

```
if @project.contest_entries.where("view_in_showcase = ?", true)
 entries = @project.contest_entries.where("view_in_showcase = ?", true).count
else
 entries = 1 
end
```

Comment: Why not just count, and if it's zero, set to one? (Which seems weird to me.)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Zero would not trigger the `else` clause in Ruby.

Comment: @Amadan ... I guess I would have thought it obvious you wouldn't use the same logical condition.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you understand that this code is fundamentally broken if you ever expect `entries` to be anything other than 0 or the count of `contest_entries`. The `entries = 1` branch will never execute. This makes the code very misleading; I'd consider fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
showcased_project_entries =
    @project.contest_entries.where("view_in_showcase = ?", true)
entries = showcased_project_entries ? showcased_project_entries.count : 1
```

or

```
entries =
    @project.contest_entries.where("view_in_showcase = ?", true).try(:count) || 1
```

Although, I must admit I am not sure under which circumstances `where` returns a falsy value.

EDIT: As noted in the comments, the `else` clause indeed never triggers, so your code probably does not do what you want. See Andy H's solution for the case where you want to have `entries` be `1` when you find no results, if that is what you meant.

Comment: I don't think this would work, `where` would return `[]` if there are no entries matching the condition.

Comment: Not here; `where` will return an empty array, which won't satisfy the ternary. Hence counting, and if the result is 0, set to one.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so. I'll edit it in... although what I wrote is equivalent to the OP's code, and I'm not a mind-reader.

Comment: Not sure how mind-reading comes in to it, but if you run the code (or similar code using an existing project's models), it's easy enough to test, and AFAICT this code won't work: with no results the if condition still evaluates to true, and `try(:count)` will work, you'll just call it on an empty array.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Which is exactly what would happen in OP's code. It comes down to "make this same, but more pretty and Rubyish" vs. "make this correct because what I wrote doesn't work"; I understood the question to be former, and my answer was a straight rewrite without changing the functionality.

Comment: @Amadan Then the *correct* answer would be to eliminate the conditional altogether, because it's non-functional. Writing wrong code shorter is still wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton: No, because it would not have demonstrated the general principle: `if x then x.f else y` can be made nicer by using `try`. The last edit clearly shows what the code does and does not do, and points to Andy H's correct answer. Fixing things for specific circumstances doesn't teach anyone anything.

Comment: @Amadan There's no "general principal" here; `try` is only useful if the object in question might not support the message. Using it in a situation where it will never work will lead to cargo-cult programming. IMO it's better to actually explain why the code is incorrect than to perpetuate the lie. YMMV, but to me, it's irresponsible. Also, using `try` is not a *general* replacement for if-else.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `max`:

```
entries = [1, @project.contest_entries.where(view_in_showcase: true).count].max
```

I would define a scope on `ContestEntry` to get rid of that `where` clause though:

```
scope :showcased, where(view_in_showcase: true)
```

Then that would become

```
entries = [1, @project.contest_entries.showcased.count].max
```

Comment: +1 for the scope, which is probably the preferred generic solution.